# Estimating Lebesgue measure

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

Let $1 \le a_1<a_2<a_3<\dots <a_q \le N$ be positive integers. Is it true that for $0<\lambda \le 1$, the Lebesgue measure of the set
$$
\{ x\in [0,N]:\,\, \sum_{j=1}^q \frac{1}{|x-a_j| }>\lambda \}
$$
is at most $ C \sqrt{ \frac{Nq}{\lambda}}$, where $C$ is an absolute constant? (It is OK if the inequality is proved with an extra factor of $1+\log \frac{1}{\lambda}$ on the right but it is not OK to have extra factors of $\log q$ on the right. Thank you in advance for any ideas related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this will require a rather careful analysis since, up to constant factor, your estimate is accurate asymptotically. Here is a simple argument that gives a weaker bound. Let$$f_i=\min\left\{\lambda, {1\over{|x-a_i|}}\right\}.$$Also, we can right away assume that $\lambda \ge q/L$ because otherwise our bound becomes trivial. Then $$\int_0^L f_i \le 2+\log tL\lesssim \log tL,$$and if we denote the set where our function is greater than $t$ by $E_t$, then
$$
t^{1/2}|E_t|\le \int_{E_t} \left( \sum f_i\right)^{1/2}\le L^{1/2}\left( \int_0^L \sum f_i\right)^{1/2}\lesssim (Lq\log tL)^{1/2} ,
$$
so we are off by a logarithmic factor, which is somewhat better than $(\log L)^{1/2}$. For small $t$, it becomes $(\log q)^{1/2}$.